# How do we calculate CD writing speed

Tags: compact-disc, cd-r

I am doing a pass paper question of my exam and I got following question. What is the maximum amount of data that can be written within 1 second to a 52X CD-R using a CD Writer with a write speed of 24X ?

When I calculate this I got 31.7.

I have two issues. Is this MB or MiB? I searched several calculation methods on google. Those provided me different values. If possible please provide me a correct algorithm to calculate this.

Comment: Well, 1x is 150KB/s. So 52x is 7800KB/s and 48x is 7200KB/s.

Comment: Thanks.The strange things is the given answers are in MB and Mib formats and more than 24 by it's value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single speed CDROMs read **up to** 75 sectors per second. A data sector on a CDROM is 2048 bytes. So read speed for an "1x CDROM" is 150 KiB/sec. I bolded 'up to' since not all drives reach this speed. Many drives from that area managed 130-140 KiB/sec.

Regardless, 150KB/sec is the current accepted speed for an 1x CDROM.

A CDROM is called 2x if it can read up to 300 KiB/sec  (2x150)
A CDROM is called 4x if it can read up to 600 KiB/sec  (4x150)
...
24 speed is  24x150 KiB/sec is **3600 KiB/sec**.

That assumes that:

- The system is generating data fast enough so you actually have something to write.
- That the writer is capable of that speed (well, that is a given in your question).
- That the medium allow writing at that speed. (Your medium allows up to 52x writing).
- That the drive is already spun up.
- That the drive is ready to write actual data. E.g. no need to start with a lead-in.

> Is this MB or MiB?

My answer is in KiB since a data sector on a CDROM is 2048 bytes, or 2 KiB.

If you want it in MB:   3600/1000 -> 3.6 MB/sec
If you want it in MiB: 3600/1024 -> 3.51 MiB/sec